# Approaches we can follow to grant certain users permission on a list item based on a multi-values People or Group field

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, flow, item-level-permissions, workflow2013

I have a custom list inside SharePoint online site collection. and i have the following requirements:-

1. Allow all users to submit new items, but they can not view any item (even the one they have created).
2. Certain users will have permission to view/edit all items.
3. when an authorized user edit an item >> they can add users inside a People or Group field named "Item Readers">> **after that the users added inside the People or Group field will have read permission on the item**

now for point 1 & 2 i will create a custom permission level to allow submit only on the list. but for point 3 i am not sure what is the best approach to follow? can i benefit from WorKflow 2013 or MS Flow? previously i use to do such a requirement using server-side event receivers, but in SharePoint online, remote event receivers are no longer been a preferred approach, especially that there is not any approach to debug them (after Microsoft has depreciated the Azure Service Bus)..

Comment: Have you thought about infopath and SPD or nintex?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Flow is recommended to achieve this requirement.

Since you already have unique permission on this list, you can skip the “Break Inheritance” part.

Please see the references below.

[Setting sharepoint item list permissions with flow.](https://noellawlor.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/setting-sharepoint-item-list-permissions-with-flow/)

[How to manage permissions on a SharePoint List Item using Microsoft Flow – changing Item permissions.](https://collab365.community/sharepoint-item-permissions-using-flow-part-1/)

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. in my case i still need to define unique permission for the item upon creation + assign the users defined inside the People or Group as Readers inside the item permission. then on update, i need to check if the People or group field was modified (or is not equal to the users defined inside the item permission), and then modify the item permission accordingly... looks like this is too much for flow or SP workflow ? is this correct?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev You can see the following link for definition limits for workflows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#definition-limits I don't think you will ever reach the limit but surely it’s a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented by the SharePoint 2010/2013 workflow. Add impersonation step then remove all permission from the created item. Also, give permission to the relevant groups/users.

Possible bug: If the user needs to submit an attachment, in some cases workflow will fail due to removing permission from the user. You need to implement a system pause that the user has enough permission to submit the attachment.